# Can I route ASP.NET Core login to different Azure B2C policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a an ASP.NET Core MVC app that I'd like to use 2 different Azure B2C authentication policies based on a user property currently stored in a database. Think along the lines of different requirements for customers vs agent as an example.

I know I can bind a single policy via config, but is there a way to dynamically pick a policy at runtime?

Comment: You can add different policies with name and then on the controller or action method you can use Authorize Attribute lile this [Authorize(Policy = "YourPolicy")]

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this is used for role/claim based policies, not Azure B2C?

Comment: Yes, but you can also add different Authentication Schemes policy, like, handling JWT, Azure AD or AWS Cognito. Your policies will have all details like client id and tenant id, or any security keys for that Authentication Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you're using Microsoft.Identity.Web then instead of your sign-in link going to `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn` have it go to a custom action you create that will populate the policy name you want to use, for example `/Account/SignIn`:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult SignIn(string? policy)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = this.Url.Content("~/"),
        };

        // in this example we're allowing the policy name to be passed in as a parameter to the action, but this would be replaced by your custom policy selection logic
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(policy))
        {
            properties.Items["policy"] = policy;

            // HACK: Microsoft.Identity.Web removes the policy item as part of the redirect to IdP but we need to update the token URL when using code flow, so fix that...
            properties.Items["customPolicy"] = policy;
        }

        return this.Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

By populating `AuthenticationProperties.Items["policy"]`, Microsoft.Identity.Web will automatically use that policy name when redirecting to the B2C `/authorize` endpoint. However, if you're using the OpenID Connect `code` flow (and you should be), you'll need to make sure the `/token` endpoint also uses the correct policy.

Microsoft.Identity.Web removes the `policy` item after the `/authorize` call, so the example above also set the policy name to `customPolicy` so it's available when tokens need to be exchanged. Simply update your Microsoft.Identity.Web configuration in `Startup.cs` to also handle the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(opt =>
        {
            // other setup here...

            opt.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived += ctx =>
            {
                if (ctx.Properties?.Items.TryGetValue("customPolicy", out var customPolicy) == true)
                {
                    ctx.TokenEndpointRequest.TokenEndpoint = $"{opt.Instance}/{opt.Domain}/{customPolicy}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        }/* cookie config happens here if you're overriding defaults */);
```

If you want this to work correctly with `[Authorize]` then you also need to change the default authentication scheme so it checks your cookies and update the cookie configuration to use your custom sign-in URL instead of the default Microsoft.Identity.Web one:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(opt =>
        {
            // other setup here...

            opt.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived += ctx =>
            {
                if (ctx.Properties?.Items.TryGetValue("customPolicy", out var customPolicy) == true)
                {
                    ctx.TokenEndpointRequest.TokenEndpoint = $"{opt.Instance}/{opt.Domain}/{customPolicy}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        },
        opt =>
        {
            // this should be the actual URL, not just the controller and action name
            opt.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";
            opt.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            opt.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply Dave, this has pointed me in the right direction I think. I'm getting the token endpoint config error "InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://XXXXX.b2clogin.com/XXXXXXXX-92eb-4bb2-8e71-XXXXXXXXXXXX/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" as the OnAuthorizationCodeReceive handler isn't getting fired. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've put my program.cs code in here to see if it sheds any light on what I'm doing wrong https://gist.github.com/jasonhyland/4da578c87fe82a1df30c9f3724c9cf39

Comment: @JasonHyland are you specifying `SignUpSignInPolicyId` in the configuration anywhere? Microsoft.Identity.Web only formats URLs as B2C URLs if that configuration property is set, otherwise it assumes you're using AAD. I think that's happening here and it's looking for the AAD metadata instead of B2C metadata.

Comment: That did the job thanks!